# Backup Azure DevOps Repositories, Workitems etc

Tags: azure, backup, devops

I would like to ask a question regarding Disaster Recovery. Earlier we used to have our own source code repo and build server, so we had a Disaster recovery plan as to restore from a backup, in case if something fails. When we moved to Azure Devops, everything including Repo , Build Piplines etc is managed by Microsoft. In that case what would be the recommended Disaster recovery strategy?

Standard answer -  most deletion operations in Azure DevOps are recoverable- is not valid in our case.
Backrightup also doesn't suit in our situation.

Comment: we have selected core components of AzureDevOps like 'GIT', pipeline(yaml) continuously fed to GitHub as part of DR. This is part of a whole DR strategy which needs holistic view of the way of working till business continuity requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about DR, the fundamental question is what kind of disasters you think of. Microsoft has its own DR, and I think they have higher reliability than what we might have in a local system.

One issue with a higher chance of happening is some internet issue, and you cannot reach the repository. Against that, the best option is checking them out in a local system.
There is a less probable issue of locking out of your DevOps account, but I imagine that you will be able to rectify it fast.

In a  DR discussion about our repos a while back, we thought it is less of a concern because of the way GIT works. GIT maintains a local repository on each of the computers that checkout the code, so you can recover most of the code if worst comes to worst.
But these situations are very subjective, so you will have to think about your case.